# Invalid character entity parsing xml

Tags: node.js, xml2js

I am trying to parse a string of xml and I getting an error

```
[Error: Invalid character entity
Line: 0
Column: 837
Char:  ]
```

Does xml not like brackets? Do I need to replace all the brackets with something like \\]. Thanks

Comment: the report starts with [ and ends with ], the bad character is before the closing bracket. Reduce your XML file until it's a few lines that still has this problem, and add that to your question. We have no idea what you're working with right now.

Comment: Basically this is part os a json object. I know it has to be some character because if I pass in a different xml it works. So its something in the xml. I wish I could post the xml but its sensitive data

Comment: Most of the xml that has brackets looks something like, "order set limit -Navigate to any product A [TBD]" without the quotes

Answer (score 13):

Ok, the invalid character was the dash and an &. I fixed it by doing the following:

```
xml = data.testSteps.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '\\n')
                    .replace(/&/g,"&amp;")
                    .replace(/-/g,"&#45;");
```

Thanks

Comment: I left replace(/[\n\r]/g, '\\n') out for performance reasons.

Answer (score 8):

Using a node domparser will get around having to do a string replace on every character that is not easily parsed as a string. This is especially useful if you have a large amount of XML to parse that may have different characters.

I would recommend [xmldom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom) as I have used it successfully with [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js)

The combined usage looks like the following:

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

var xmlString = "<test>some stuff </test>";
var xmlStringSerialized = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");
    parseString(xmlStringSerialized, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            //did not work
        } else {
            //worked! use JSON.stringify() 
            var allDone = JSON.stringify(result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Seems really counter performant to invoque DOMParser just so that xml2js will not choke on nasty characters.
Would anyone know a more bullet proof xml -> js object alternative?
Thanks anyway, you saved my day.