# How can I parse this XML with xml2js?

Tags: json, xml, node.js, parsing

I have some XML that I'm trying to parse (using xml2js).

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var json;

var XMLPath = './public/tsa.ibm.com/meijer/gpfs_hacmp_powersc.xml';
var rawJSON = loadXMLDoc(XMLPath);

function loadXMLDoc(filePath) {
  try {
    var fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'ascii');

    var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
    parser.parseString(fileData.substring(0, fileData.length), function(err, result) {
       console.log(err);
       console.log(result);
       json = JSON.stringify(result);
       console.log("JSON:");
       console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    });

    console.log("File '" + filePath + "/ was successfully read.\n");
       return json;
  } catch (exception) {
    console.log(exception);
  }
}
```

> [Error: Invalid character in entity name Line: 44 Column: 123 Char: =]

On that line, the code is: `<value xs:nil="true" />`

I'm not sure what's going on here. :( Could anyone please help? I haven't really tried anything. I'm not sure what to even try.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try changing var parser = new xml2js.Parser(); to var parser = new xml2js.Parser({attrkey:"'$'"});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid character entity parsing xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877085/invalid-character-entity-parsing-xml)